# How to override the update action in django rest framework ModelViewSet?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

These are the demo models

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=5)

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_lenght=50)
    body = models.TextField()
```

And the respective views are

```
class AuthorViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Author.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AuthorSerializer

class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostStatSerializer
```

I am trying to perform an update/put action on PostViewSet and which is succesfull, but I am  expecting different output. After successful update of Post record, I want to send its Author record as output with AuthorSerializer. How to override this and add this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out some less code fix for my issue.

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostStatSerializer

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().update(request, *args, **kwargs)
        instance = self.get_object()
        return Response(AuthorSerializer(instance.author).data)
```

Comment: Please note that this method leads to double DB calls. Because firstly `instance = self.get_object()` is performed inside `super().update(request, *args, **kwargs)` and later it will be repeated.

Comment: Noted. I tried to collect the return value of `super().update(request, *args, **kwargs)` but it's returning None and I have no option but to call it again. :(

Answer (score 5):

You can override `update` method for this:

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostStatSerializer

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)

        # this will return autor's data as a response 
        return Response(AuthorSerializer(instance.parent).data)
```

Comment: AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `title` on serializer `PostStatSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Author` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Author' object has no attribute 'title'.

Comment: @Jitendra can you show your code and full trace back?

Comment: The actual tables are a bit complex to show, but I am testing with the same demo tables and code.

Comment: @Jitendra ok, what about traceback? Are you sure you use `AuthorSerializer(instance.parent).data`? It's `instance.parent` not `instance`.

Comment: Yes, I am sure, I just copied your code and pasted there.

Comment: @Jitendra can you show full traceback of the error?

Comment: Hi, I figured it out by tweaking the update method from last few hours, and your code is also working as well. I tested your code with default Django(DRF) default API client, strangely it's throwing error even with my code, and then I tested with postman and both the codes are working. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248213/discussion-between-jitendra-and-neverwalkaloner).